# PHP Editor that able to trace dependency of all function in a file with models/controllers or another part of a framework (or something we had code)

Tags: php, notepad++

hello a friend of mind ask something about php editor for his companion on coding.

PHP Editor that able to trace dependency of all function in a file with models/controllers or another part of a framework (or something we had code).

Basicly we use notepad++ but seeking another alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used Eclipse PDT, Aptana, Netbeans, and Komodo. For Web development (at least my style: PHP, Python, Perl, HTML, JavaScript, Ruby, CSS, all the goodies) nothing has touched **Komodo IDE**. There is a free/open source version called Open Komodo that, unfortunately, is not as feature complete as Komodo IDE but still great.

It runs on Windows, Linux, and Mac (which is a plus since I use all three at times), is completely extendible through plugins, has source code repository features, file transfer features (s/ftp, scp, etc) and so much more. What it really wins on is polish (things like multi-language/library code auto complete).

Answer (score 2):

Komodo ide.  Able to set up included libraries on the path.  Full featured local and remote debugging.  As a bonus it runs on Windows / Linux and Mac.

http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend NetBeans (netbeans.org).  I've had great luck with it, and using the "Included Files" portion, you can include files outside the website source, so it's able to analyze back through something like CakePHP.  The latest release includes support for Symfony too.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend Eclipse and [Aptana Studio 1.5](http://docs.aptana.com/docs/index.php/Plugging_Aptana_into_an_existing_Eclipse_configuration#Aptana_Studio_1.5_on_Eclipse_3.5_Instructions_.28Recommend.29) (which is much better than the PDT plugin for Eclipse). I use it daily for some very large PHP projects on Windows PCs and Macs.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [nWire for PHP](http://www.nwiresoftware.com/products/nwire-php). It is an Eclipse PDT plugin which provides real-time code analysis and exploration. You can easily browse and even visualize all kinds of dependencies within your code.

Comment: wow really, it has visual presentation. it's will be better. i will try it